# python - is it possible to concat column after using pandas get_dummies?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my example df

```
         doc_num
doc1 doc2 
 A    B    U123
 A    C    U123
 A    D    U124
 B    C    U126
 B    D    U126
```

and i have use

```
pd.get_dummies(df.doc_num).sort_index(level=0)
```

to make a vector matrix like this

```
           U123 U124 U126
doc1 doc2  
 A    B     1    0    0
 A    C     1    0    0
 A    D     0    1    0
 B    C     0    0    1
 B    D     0    0    1
```

but i would like to concat the doc1 and doc2 then create a new column to see the expected result like this

```
       U123 U124 U126
doc_3  
 A,B     1    0    0
 A,C     1    0    0
 A,D     0    1    0
 B,C     0    0    1
 B,D     0    0    1
```

is it possible? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need join both levels of `MultiIndex`, set index name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.doc_num).sort_index(level=0)
df1.index = df1.index.map(','.join)
df1 = df1.rename_axis('doc_3')
print (df1)
       U123  U124  U126
doc_3                  
A,B       1     0     0
A,C       1     0     0
A,D       0     1     0
B,C       0     0     1
B,D       0     0     1
```

And add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column if necessary:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  doc_3  U123  U124  U126
0   A,B     1     0     0
1   A,C     1     0     0
2   A,D     0     1     0
3   B,C     0     0     1
4   B,D     0     0     1
```

---

Or first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to columns from `MultiIndex` with [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns if want index:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.doc_num).sort_index(level=0).reset_index()
df1.index =  df1.pop('doc1') + ',' + df1.pop('doc2')
df1 = df1.rename_axis('doc_3')
print (df1)
       U123  U124  U126
doc_3                  
A,B       1     0     0
A,C       1     0     0
A,D       0     1     0
B,C       0     0     1
B,D       0     0     1
```

---

Or use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for new column:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.doc_num).sort_index(level=0).reset_index()
df1.insert(0, 'doc_3',  df1.pop('doc1') + ',' + df1.pop('doc2'))

print (df1)
  doc_3  U123  U124  U126
0   A,B     1     0     0
1   A,C     1     0     0
2   A,D     0     1     0
3   B,C     0     0     1
4   B,D     0     0     1
```

Comment: @U9-Forward - Added both solutions - for index and for columns too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jezrael's answer, you want a vector matrix, so do:

```
df1=pd.get_dummies(df.doc_num)
df1.insert(0, 'doc_3',  df['doc1'] + ',' + df['doc2'])
print(df1.set_index('doc_3'))
```

Or:

```
df1=pd.get_dummies(df.doc_num)
df1['doc_3']=df.pop('doc1') + ',' + df.pop('doc2')
print(df1.set_index('doc_3'))
```

All Output:

```
       U123  U124  U126
doc_3                  
A,B       1     0     0
A,C       1     0     0
A,D       0     1     0
B,C       0     0     1
B,D       0     0     1
```

Now you really get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. It will combine two columns into one . Also, add "," in between them.

```
df['doc_3'] = df['doc1'] + "," + df['doc2']
```

Then you can drop first two columns